# How to restore old commit dialog window in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, jetbrains-ide

Hi I installed Android Studio Canary. I cannot see the commit window, it is completely changed. I want to get the old version back without changing Android Studio. Here is my current commit window looks like

[image]

Answer (score 34, accepted):

### Android Studio Arctic Fox+

In latest versions of Android Studio, use either

1. Click the settings gear/cog icon and select `Switch to commit dialog`

   [image]

---

2. (or) go to `File > Settings > Version Control > Commit` check `Use non-modal commit`

   [image]

---

### Android studio till Arctic Fox

You can change it from the settings. Go to `File > Settings> Version Control > Commit Dialog` and on the right pane, `untick` the option saying "Commit from Local Changes without showing the Commit dialog".
Then click apply.

[image]